# Problems migrating a class from linux to windows - Urllib.request

Tags: python, linux, windows, urllib

I had this class that performed perfectly in Linux.

```
class UrlRequestor(object):
    def __init__(self, url, headers, data):
        self.url = url
        self.headers = headers
        self.request = urllib2.Request(url)
        self.data = data
        self.data = data
        if self.data:
            self.request.add_data(self.data)
        for headerName, headerContent in self.headers.iteritems():
            self.request.add_header(headerName, headerContent)
    def open(self):
        self.content = urllib2.urlopen(self.request)
    def getHeader(self, headerName):
        return self.content.info().getheader(headerName)
    def getReturnData(self):
        return dict(json.loads(self.content.read()))
    def getRawReturn(self):
        return self.content.read()}
```

Which I have been trying to run on windows - with many errors including indentation I finally became stuck at this point.

I am apparently missing a 'positional argument' for the add_data method. Although I believe this is a symptom of a larger problem.

Here is the code as I have it.

```
class UrlRequestor(object):
    def __init__(self, url, headers, data):
        self.url = url
        self.headers = headers
        self.request = urllib2.Request(url)
        self.data = data
        self.data = data
        if self.data:
            self.request.add_data(self.data)
        for headerName, headerContent in self.headers.iteritems():

            self.request.add_header(headerName, headerContent)
    def open(self):
        self.content = urllib2.urlopen(self.request)
    def getHeader(self, headerName):
        return self.content.info().getheader(headerName)
    def getReturnData(self):
        return dict(json.loads(self.content.read()))
    def getRawReturn(self):
        return self.content.read()
```

I don't mind reading, I don't mind point in the right direction. At this point I am pretty stumped, and a little pointing wouldn't hurt.

Many thanks guys.

*EDIT*********************************************************

For future information check the python version, installed 2.7.3 and ran exactly same code as on linux without a problem.

Comment: Well, start at the indentation errors and work from there.  Are you using any Unix-exclusive libraries?  It doesn't _appear_ like you are, but double-checking that would be a good idea.  Also, which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I fixed the indentation errors using the tab to spaces feature of Jedit (I'm just terrible at posting code here apparently).

The errors I am getting are around the module not having the attributes 'urlopen' >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with Python 2.7.x, then place `import urllib2` at the beginning of your file.

If you're working with Python 3.x, then [observe the note](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) regarding the change to the `urllib` family of libraries in Python 3.x:

> Note: The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named urllib.request and urllib.error. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

For your case, the library you want to use can be found in [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urllib2#urllib.request.urlopen).

Alternatively, on your Windows machine, elect to use the same version of Python that you have on your Linux box.  There may be some other caveats in using Python 3.x on two platforms with the same code base that you're not entirely accounting for.

Comment: Very useful, thank you. I am now having an error regarding how post data must be an iterable of bytes?